# Django generate choice field from range

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi I have a django form choice field, which needs a choice selection of range 85-150 at 5 unit increments. Unfortunately I can't do this:

```
wind_range = range(85, 150, 5)

WIND_SPEED_CHOICE = (
    for i in wind_range:
        (i, i),
)
```

Any suggestions?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [django model field reference doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> Finally, note that choices can be any iterable object -- not
>   necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices
>   dynamically.

This means that this can be a solution to you:

```
wind_range = range(85, 150, 5)    
WIND_SPEED_CHOICE =  [ (i, i) for i in wind_range ]
```